# Python 3.7 Indentation error when importing pandas as pd

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am simply running `import pandas as pd` to import pandas.
I am getting an indentation error which I am unable to understand.

I have updated everything using Anaconda.
I have attempted to import pandas in Spyder and Jupyter Notebook

my error message:

```py
import pandas as pd

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3296, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-2-3f7aa48ad27f>", line 3, in <module>
    import pandas as pd

  File "C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from pandas.io.api import *

  File "C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\api.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pandas.io.excel import ExcelFile, ExcelWriter, read_excel

  File "C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 34, in <module>
    from pandas.io.parsers import TextParser

  File "C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1122
    L            self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
                                                                      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Answer (score 3):

Reinstall `pandas`. I'd imagine the file has been edited somehow, introducing that indentation error.

Comment: ... In fact, looking more closely at the exception, it's obvious there's a stray `L` at the beginning of that line.